# How do I set up Azure API Management to accept POST with form data fields and pass them through to a legacy API

Tags: multipartform-data, azure-api-management

I have a legacy API that is expecting to be called by POST of a form with 3 form fields (each containing a string). I would like to wrap this call in the Azure API Management.

I'm hoping I've missed something basic, but I assumed that the API service would pass through what it received to my legacy API.

I created:
 - an api
 - an operation (POST)
 - a backend service
 - credentials to login to backend service

I can call the service through either the test link or through postman. It definitely is hitting the backend API - but it doesn't seem to be passing my multi-part form fields with it.

Do I need to create a representation?

Any links to guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing for setting up a token API which communicates with AAD API and it accepts the form data. I accept the `ClientId` and `ClienSecret` in my APIM exposed API as input. e.g.

```
{
 "ClientID":"",
 "ClientSecret": ""
}
```

This is passed to the backend as shown below

```
 <set-backend-service base-url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/someguid/oauth2/v2.0" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                JObject request = JObject.Parse(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent:true));

                string clientId = (string)request?["ClientId"];
                string clientSecret = (string)request?["ClientSecret"];
                string scope = "api://someguid/.default";
                string grantType = "client_credentials";
                string response = $"client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={scope}&grant_type={grantType}";
                return response;
                }</set-body>
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try the above yet. Got another unrelated issue to solve first. I'll update this answer when I get back to it. Thanks!